# Cannot install and configure USB-C-to-Ethernet Adapter on HoloLens 2

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I need to install a physical network adapter on the Holo2. I purchased a high-quality adapter from a reputable vendor. I've looked everywhere and Googled quite a bit but can't seem to get an answer. The adapter does show up under the 'Devices' section, but if I click on it, nothing happens. Also, if I try to add a device myself it never finds it. I just get the screen that reminds me to turn it on make it available.

Any guidance is enormously appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the device requires additional drivers then there could be a problem if you would see [connect devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/hololens/hololens-connect-devices). You should check the information provided in the associated chapter regarding your device.

Does it have to be an adapter on the Hololens itself. I would rather suggest an Ethernet to Wifi Adapter on the PC, if this is in any way possible.

I hope this helps in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Networking should just work plug-and-play. If you need help with your device please open a support case at http://aka.ms/hololenssupport. Device configuraction issues are off topic on StackOverflow.